# SQL Server bulk insert XML format file with Maximum LENGTH

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, bulkinsert

I want to set the length to MAX for one of my XML fields.

XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
    <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="3" />
    <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="MAXLENGTH"  />
    <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="10" />
    <FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="8" />

 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="Field1" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="Field2" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="Field3" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="4" NAME="Field4" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>   
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

But 'MAXLENGTH' does not seem to work.

Error message:

```
bad value MAXLENGTH for attribute "LENGTH"
```

Any suggestions on how to put the LENGTH to maximum ?

Comment: Are you trying to import into a `varchar(max)` field? Would switching to a text format file which does not worry about widths make things easier?

Comment: Hi, is this question solved? Do you need further help?

Answer (score 0):

The length of a string is limited to 4000 (nchar) or 8000 (char) type. There is no `max length`-constant - AFAIC

Refer to [this, "Field Attributes"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187833.aspx)

If you look up the schema *meta-data* just as SQL Server does, you can follow this link

http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format/bulkloadschema.xsd

to find this

```
<xsd:attribute name="LENGTH" type="xsd:positiveInteger" use="required"/>
[...]
<xsd:attribute name="MAX_LENGTH" type="xsd:positiveInteger" use="optional"/>
```

So the `length` is `required` while `max_length` seems to be `optional`, but if you specify it, it must be a positive integer.